# Как сменить MAC-адрес в MikroTik

Tags: маршрутизатор, mikrotik

Как сменить MAC-адрес в MikroTik?

Answer (score 5):

MAC-адрес можно сменить вот такой командой:

```
/interface ethernet set ether1 mac-address=00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```